# How to get to next object in foreach

Tags: android, android-studio

Im making a quizz app in android studio.I have a slight issue. I display the questions and answers fine, but when the user click on a button, be it right or wrong answer, i want the next question to come.
I feel its really stupid, but heres what i did.

```
private void getListe() {
        
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                QuizzController quizzController = new QuizzController(GameActivity.this);//bon contexte?
                liste = quizzController.getGame(difficulte, categorie, nb);

        handlerGame.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this,"gg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        for(QuizzRoom q : liste ){
                            tvQuestion.setText(q.question);
                            btnBadAnswer.setText(q.mauvaisesReponses);
                            btnGoodAnswer.setText(q.bonneReponse);
                        }

                        btnGoodAnswer.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                            score+=10;
                             tvScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));


                        });
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();private void getListe() {
        
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                QuizzController quizzController = new QuizzController(GameActivity.this);//bon contexte?
                liste = quizzController.getGame(difficulte, categorie, nb);

        handlerGame.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this,"gg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        for(QuizzRoom q : liste ){
                            tvQuestion.setText(q.question);
                            btnBadAnswer.setText(q.mauvaisesReponses);
                            btnGoodAnswer.setText(q.bonneReponse);
                        }

                        btnGoodAnswer.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                            score+=10;
                             tvScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));


                        });
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
```

I cannot figure how to get to the next QuizzRoom object (answer+questions). Feels like it should just come right on when the loop  starts over, but it doesnt.

Thanks in advance for any tips in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way but it should work:

```
private int questionsCount;



  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        QuizzController quizzController = new QuizzController(GameActivity.this);//bon contexte?
        liste = quizzController.getGame(difficulte, categorie, nb);

        //get the size of the list
        questionsCount = liste.size()

handlerGame.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this,"gg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                btnGoodAnswer.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    score+=10;
                    //will remove the last question form the count
                    questionsCount--
                     tvScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    showQuestion(liste)

                });
            }
        });

    }
}).start();

void showQuestion(List<QuizzRoom> questions){

   //here you should check if there are any questions left
   // if(questionsCount < 0) do something
    QuizzRoom q = questions[questionsCount]
    tvQuestion.setText(q.question);
    btnBadAnswer.setText(q.mauvaisesReponses);
    btnGoodAnswer.setText(q.bonneReponse);
}
```

Comment: thanks, thats was it. i used an incremental counter, but its the same